# Program that finds and prints all prime numbers 1-100 to a file

Tags: java

I have a homework assignment and I'm stuck. the program compiles fine but when I run it, it only prints the number 1 into the file and ends. I've googled this problem dozens of times and all solutions involve try and catch statements which my professor will not accept because we haven't learned it in class yet.
Here is my code:

```
`import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class K_Topple_Chap5_Prime_NumList_Redo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    String filename; //filename used to open file
    boolean isPrime;
    int num1 = 1;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //needed for scanner class

    System.out.print("Enter a directory for a file: "); //asks user for name 
of file
     filename = keyboard.nextLine(); //sets input equal to filename

    File file = new File(filename); //sets input filename = file variable
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file); //opens file
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file); //creates printwriter 
for file

    for(num1 = 1; num1 <= 100; num1++) //for statement that runs 98 times to 
test every number between 1-100 for primality
    {
      isPrime = isPrime(num1); //calls isprime method and tests primality 
and sets isPrime to boolean value
      if(isPrime == true) //if isPrime is true then it prints that number to 
the file
      {
        printWriter.println(num1 + " "); //prints num1 to file
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Done."); //when the for statement is done running it 
prints done
    printWriter.close (); //closes file
  }

  /**This method tests if a number is prime
    * @param num1 holds the current number being tested
    * @return returns true or false if number is prime or not
    * 
   */
  public static boolean isPrime(double num1) //isprime method used to test 
if a number is prime
  {
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= num1; i++) 
     {
      if (num1 % i == 0) 
       {
        return false;
       }
     }
    return true;
  }
}
`
```

I tried putting comments in to make it easier for people to understand, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `isPrime()` will always return false once `i` hits `num1`. Change the loop condition to `i < num1`.

Comment: Use the IDE's debugger and step through the code to figure out what's happening and why it's exiting.

Comment: logic used in method to check if the number is prime itself is not correct.

Comment: `boolean isPrime(double num)` — why the switch to `double` for the prime number check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every number is divisible by the number itself, you are getting `false` from the function. Just change the loop condition from `i <= num1` to `i < num1`.

```
for (i = 2; i < num1; i++) {
    if (num1 % i == 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will return the correct flag..u can maintain a flag and based on that flag return true or false.

```
int i,flag=0;
for (i = 2; i <= num1/2; i++) 
 {
  if (num1 % i == 0) 
   {
     flag=1;      
     return true;   
   }
 }
if(flag==0)
return flase;
```